# NSCollectionView: центрирование итемов

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, macos

Есть `NSCollectionView`, в него добавлены элементы (программно, не через байндинги). При изменении размера окна горизонтально (`NSCollectionView`) появляется пустое пространство, а потом при определенном размере, в пустое пространство добавляются элементы из нижних частей `NSCollectionView`. Как можно отцентрировать итемы во время ресайза окна `NSCollectionView`, до тех пор пока не добавятся новые элементы из нижних строк `NSCollectionView`? Идеи? Решения? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Центрирование итемов (выравнивание их относительно ширины NSCollectionView) реализовано расширением ширины итема. Сначала узнаем сколько относительно ширины NSCollectionView помещается итемов и потом вычисляем ширину итема, и расстягиваем их на всю ширину NSCollectionView.